# How compare two json objects by only key?

Tags: c#, json, compare

I have two json objects and I compare them, But it is compared by key and value,
And I want to compare two json objects by only key,
How do I it?

This my code:

```
var jdp = new JsonDiffPatch();
var areEqual2 = jdp.Diff(json1, json2);
```

Comment: Please look into this link   https://jsfiddle.net/4ze7ksx6/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could achive this is by retrieving the names/path of all keys in json and comparing the List. For example,

```
var path1 = GetAllPaths(json1).OrderBy(x=>x).ToList();
var path2 = GetAllPaths(json2).OrderBy(x=>x).ToList();
var result = path1.SequenceEqual(path2);
```

Where GetAllPaths is defined as

```
private IEnumerable<string> GetAllPaths(string json)
{
    var regex = new Regex(@"\[\d*\].",RegexOptions.Compiled);
    return JObject.Parse(json).DescendantsAndSelf()
                   .OfType<JProperty>()
                   .Where(jp => jp.Value is JValue)
                   .Select(jp => regex.Replace(jp.Path,".")).Distinct();
}
```

[Sample Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0vEd1B)

Comment: Hi,Thank you it is work well, but I need get the diffrents json this function return boolean,

Comment: @NirAmir Do you mean, you need all the keys that are different ?

Comment: Almost, I need all the same keys.

Comment: @NirAmir didn't understand you. So you need all the different Json Keys or you want a list of common Json Keys ? and what about Values, do you need them as well ? It would have been great if you could update the question with sample json and expected output

Answer (score 1):

you can create and use a class like this:

```
class CustomComparer : IEqualityComparer<YourObjectType> 
{  

    public bool Equals(YourObjectType first, YourObjectType second) 
    {  
        if (first == null | second == null) { return false; } 

        else if (first.Hash == second.Hash) 
            return true; 

        else return false;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(YourObjectType obj)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a different between 2 json:

```
       private List<string> GetDiff(List<string> path1, List<string> path2)
    {
        List<string> equal=new List<string>();

        foreach (var j1 in path1)
        {
            foreach (var j2 in path2)
            {
                if (j1 == j2)
                {
                    equal.Add(j1);
                }
            }   
        }        
        return equal;
    }
```